# Uploading scores with GameKit

Tags: iphone, nsdata, gamekit, game-center

How do I save and upload scores later if there is no connection available? In a WWDC session it says to use the following code if no connection is available:

```
NSData *archivedScore = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[NSData dataWithBytes:&score length:sizeof(score)]];
```

I then save the NSData object to NSUSerDefaults. But how do I get an int score value back from that to report?

Thanks

Comment: You serialize an integer and then serialize the wrapper again? You might have more success if you serialize it again, so that it can't escape! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSKeyedUnarchiver` (from [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/serializing.html))

```
int score = 42;
NSData *archivedScore = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[NSData dataWithBytes:&score length:sizeof(score)]];
int *scorePtr = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:archivedScore] bytes];
NSLog(@"score = %d", *scorePtr); // Output: score = 42
```